# C# Selenium: Any other way to get TEXT value of IWebElement faster?

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I get 500+ elements by `FindElements(By.Xpath)`.

But when I loop them to get text value, it takes 30+ seconds.

This is very slow and unacceptable.

I am using this code:

```
var obj = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath...); // fast enough for 500 elements
int count = obj.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string a = obj.ElementAt(i).Text; // long time, approx 0.05 sec
    Debug.print(a); // long time, approx 0.05 sec
}
// total takes 30secs appox. just for printing text values of 500 elements.
```

I tried with `By.CssSelector`, but not big difference.

And this is xpath string example I am using:

```
"//wpsel-app/div[@class='wpsel-app-wrapper']/wpsel-sport/div/div/div/section/div/div[@class='wpsel-eventBloc']/div/wpsel-event-main/div/wpsel-event-main-normal/a[@class='wpsel-bloc']/div[@class='wpsel-blocRight']/wpsel-market-offer-event/div[@class='buttonGroup']/div[@class='buttonLine u-ovh']/div[@class='buttonLine-item']/button[@class='outcomeButton']/span[@class='outcomeButton-data']"
```

Some long and I don't think this issue is from long xpath string.

Any trick for this problem?

Comment: without print how long it take? the fastest you can get is not using selenium but `Regex`

Comment: Good hint, @ewwink, Thanks!